# Using curl to load an HTML file that submit an external form with JS

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I need a little help here:

I have 2 files

- index.php
- form0.html

form0.html automatically fill a form and send it.
When I go straight to the fill it works fine, but when I try to access it through my php script it won't work unless I print the results.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(30);
$delay_time = 2; // time to wait before looping again.
$loop_times = 1; // number of times to loop.
$url = array("http://localhost/htmlfile0.html");

for($x=0;$x<$loop_times;$x++)
{
    echo count($url);
    for($i=0;$i<count($url);$i++)
    {
        $url1=$url[$i];
        $curl = curl_init(); // Initialize the cURL handler

        $header = array();
        $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 30000";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.
        $var_host = parse_url($url1,PHP_URL_HOST);


        $cookieJar = 'cookies/'.$var_host.'.txt'; // change it according to your requirement. make dynamic for multi URL
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); // Browser like header
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);  // file for cookies if site requires
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar); // file for cookies if site requires

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Follow any redirects, just in case
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // set curl to return the page

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); //post the form

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url1); // Set the URL
        $ch=curl_exec($curl); // Display page                  
        curl_close($ch); // Close cURL handler

        echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
        if($ch) echo "Success: ".$url1;
        else echo "Fail: ".$url1;
        echo '<hr>';
        sleep(5);
        echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
    }
    if($x < $loop_times) sleep($delay_time);
}
?>
```

How can I get pass this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you're trying to execute JS using CURL request which you cant' at least not directly.

When you go straight to file, it works fine - your browser's JS interpreter executes JS proprerly and form is submitted, but by using cURL you are doing something different - you are sending http request headers to certain URL(http://localhost/htmlfile0.html) and you may and may not fetch the response content.

If you do fetch the content (and parse JS in your browser's js interpreter) javascript **may be** set to refuse correct action based on wheather it is or it is not correct url.

Example:

*do some action if it is right URL* - if you reached code on `http://example.com/script.html`

*do not do anything if it's not above URL* - and that's the case when you perform action using your cURL php script to reach above URL with and to output document's code in `http://localhost`.